# Which HTTP library is better? Wget, cUrl, LibWWW or ...?

Tags: curl, libcurl, wget

Which library is better for HTTP? [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), [LibWWW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibWWW) or any thing else?

I want a portable C/C++ library.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wget is **not** a HTTP library, it is an application. Calling this programmatically using `system()` or similar calls is disrecommended.

cURL is also not a HTTP library, but it's backend is libcurl. This libcurl is one of the most used HTTP libraries in C and C++ in the world. When you read cURL in a programming context you can often assume they mean libcurl, and not the application cURL.

Choosing between libcurl and LibWWW I think most would go with libcurl (I would). Quoting Wikipedia:

> libcurl is considered to be a modern replacement for libwww

Comment: @HaloWebMaster: read directly from a socket *and make your own HTTP client*, compensating for various server and protocol quirks? I'm not attracted to the pain associated with reinventing this particular wheel, thank you very much. (It's a great learning experience though, both in HTTP and TCP/IP)

Comment: I was kidding, though I agree with the learning part (I have had to do this, not fun).

Comment: wget has library too, its part of `wget` package (it's as you call it "backend")

Answer (score 3):

This list is very complete:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html

Comment: No it's not complete it only lists free open source software.

Answer (score 0):

wget2 has a backend library. Code using the library can be compiled with `lwget` flag. Give it a try.

https://gnuwget.gitlab.io/wget2/reference/